# In pattern printing questions, is answer that just hardcode and print the desired output 'not an answer'?

Tags: discussion, not-an-answer

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33350488) is found on a question asking about printing a pattern, but looks like just copying the desired output as string and print it again. But I believe,in most cases whenever OP asks about printing pattern , a dynamic way to print such pattern is preferred. Is that answer obsolete?

Comment: According to the comment to this answer, it is just a joke: it points that question itself is bad and doesn't provide info which is needed. As a rule, in case of reviewing answer to a **bad question**, **the question should be processed first**. As for the answer itself, it is an *answer* (not NAA), because the question is formulated such. But you are free to downvote it. Good formulation of the question, probably, will invalidate given answer (as you say, OP usually wants *printing pattern*, which is applicable to *parameterized* task).